# Doxygen for verilog code

Tags: doxygen, doxywizard

I need to document my verilog code using Doxygen. I've installed doxygen version 1.8.10 and doxverilog version 2.6. Moreover, I've xilinx 12.0 and microsoft visual studio 2010 for windows 64 bit. I've followed the following steps and need guidance more as I'm very new to this Doxygen software.

1. Copy the Verilog files verilogparser.y verlogscanner.l and the others source    files from "C:\Doxverilog2.7\sources" to the "C:\doxygen-1.8.10\src".
2. Copy the patch file "windows.patch" from "C:\Doxverilog2.7\sources" to the   "C:\doxygen-1.8.10".

The next step is mentioned in the "ReadMe" file of "Doxverilog2.7" as:
    **open a shell in the doxygen-1.8.1 directory
    make  patch  # patch -F3 -p1  < windows.patch**

but how do I open it? and what is meant by this shell? From where I can get it?

The next step is provided as"Open doxygen-1.8.1\winbuild\Doxygen.vcproj with Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition" but when I build this project in Visual Studio 2010 then it gives me several errors and it is not successfully built. Is there any such project that can be run on visual studio 2010 instead of visual studio 2008?

Also, I want to use Doxywizard so, do I need to follow these steps? Please help me out of this problem.

Thank-you.